# In ASP.NET how to identify/process 404 exceptions?

Tags: asp.net, exception, http-status-code-404

I need to handle 404 exceptions differently than all other types of them. What is the best way to identify those 404 exceptions (distinguish them from other exceptions)?

The problem is that there is no a special exception class for 404 errors, I get regular System.Web.HttpException with Message = "File does not exist."

Should I just use exception's message for it or is there a better way?

Thank you.

Comment: Handle where? In Global.asax application error handler? In code that's calling out to another ASP.NET application (i.e., a web client)?

Comment: Handle in global.asax on the server side.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try to cast the exception as an `HttpException`, and then use the `GetHttpCode` method to check whether it is a 404 or not.

For example:

```
Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

HttpException httpEx = ex as HttpException;

if (httpEx != null && httpEx.GetHttpCode() == 404)
{
   //do what you want for 404 errors
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest that you configure your application to redirect 404 errors to a specific page, such as `~/FourOhFour.aspx`. In this page you can inspect the `aspxerrorpath` querystring parameter, which will report the page the user was attempting to visit. From here you can do all sorts of interesting things, from logging the 404, to emailing yourself a message, to trying to determine the correct URL and auto-redirecting the user to that.

To configure your web application to redirect the user to a custom page in the face of a 404, add the following markup to `web.config` in the `<system.web>` section:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/GeneralError.aspx">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/FourOhFour.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

For more information, see:

- [`<customErrors>` element documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I'm doing all that already, but this is not a problem. My problem is that the exception is still thrown in global.asax even if redirect worked and I need to handle it there. How can I tell that the exception is HTTP 404 and not the other one?

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the exception. You're trying to catch this in a client application, correct?

```
HttpWebRequest req = ( HttpWebRequest )WebRequest.Create( someURL );
try
{
    HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
}
catch( WebException webEx )
{
   if( webEx.Response != null )
   {
      HttpWebResponse response = webEx.Response as HttpWebResponse;
      switch( response.StatusCode )
      {
         case HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
             // do something
             break;
```

Comment: Nope, this is a pure server side: global.asax. I have no problem catching the exception, my problem is to identify it as HTTP 404.

Answer (score 1):

In the Web.Config file you can specifiy a seperate File for each error code.

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
```

Comment: I'm doing this already, but exception I described is still thrown and I still need to handle it properly in global.asax.